How to access secrets locally (Replicate external secret Operator)
This is a more open-ended question but I hope it is allowed here. I am currently tasked with replacing the Jasypt library which we use to decrypt secrets in our applications. For now the course of action we've decided upon is to use the Hashicorp Vault (which we already have in use anyway) with the external secrets operator (https://github.com/external-secrets/external-secrets) in our Kubernetes Cluster.
We are just using Java with Spring Boot but I do not think this is relevant to this question.
The question that came up now is how would we be able to use secrets locally for testing. For security reasons we don't want to use the same secrets we use in the cluster locally but how would we best go about doing it?
I have a couple of ideas and thoughts.
Firstly we need to decide if we want to have the dev and prod secrets in the same Vault instance, we could just deploy a dev instance of Vault, with the same structure as the prod vault and use this.
Secondly we need to decide how we can access either of these vaults. These ideas all have trade-offs and some are just plain bad but I wanted to just put them out there.

We could deploy a kubernetes cluster locally with the ESO functionality, I don't think this is worth it or would work particularly well.
We could write a library that accesses the vault with the dev secrets, this would just need the dev key for the vault, which would work similar to the decrpytion key we had to distribute for Jasypt
We could just put Dev Secrets into the application itself, they are after all just Dev secrets (Theoretically possible, not suggested)
We could access the remote Kubernetes Cluster and have a pod in there access the Vault and distribute the secrets.
I am open for suggestions

